# Ruby on Rails Scaffolds Community Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I'm a noob to rails, and am learning some of its cool features.  I'm really impressed by the scaffolds - they seem to be generic frameworks for things like blogs etc.

Is there a community resource where other scaffolds can be found?  I'd like, for instance, to create a site that has an image slideshow or similar where a user can log in and upload photos to add to the slideshow and delete existing images or change the order or effects, time etc.

I'm sure that I can amend the Posts scaffold to do something along these lines, like I say I'm a noob at the moment and learning by doing is good, but I see that there is a way of [making your own scaffolds](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html), so I wondered if some kind person had made any scaffolds available.

Many thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these for application templates

- [Rails Composer](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer)
- [perlang](http://prelang.com/)
- [drone.bz](https://github.com/recombinary/dronr)
- [Suspenders](https://github.com/thoughtbot/suspenders)

Comment: Thanks! drone.bz is down and is now https://github.com/recombinary/dronr.
I was really after a site that had predefined application templates rather than template builders but the Rails Composer will really help learning and perlang is just like wow!...  When I've learnt a bit more about RoR then Suspenders looks like a great foundation.  Thanks Again!